# Como pegar dados de um array sem usar o Índice

Tags: php, json, api, codeigniter-3

Estou tentando pegar dados por meio de uma API (bet365) ela retorna esses dados em JSON, criei uma função para extrair esses dados e transformar em array

Segue função:
       public function api_futebol(){

```
  $url = "https://api.betsapi.com/v1/bet365/inplay_filter?sport_id=1&token=token&LNG_ID=22" . $this->refcode;


  $request_headers = array();
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);

  if (curl_errno($ch))
    {
    print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
    }
    else
    {
    // Show me the result

    $transaction = json_decode($data, TRUE);

    curl_close($ch);

   //var_dump($transaction);

   $dados = array();

   $dados['transaction'] = $transaction;
  }

       $this->load->view('header');
       $this->load->view('home', $dados);
       $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

Modelo do JSON que estou trabalhando:

```
{
"success": 1,
"pager": {
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 1000,
    "total": 4
},
"results": [
    {
        "id": "77564080",
        "time": "1543528800",
        "time_status": "1",
        "league": {
            "id": "3024",
            "name": "Copa Libertadores - Feminino"
        },
        "home": {
            "id": "9105",
            "name": "EC Iranduba - Feminino"
        },
        "away": {
            "id": "170148",
            "name": "Atlético Huila - Feminino"
        },
        "ss": "1-0",
        "our_event_id": "1093051"
    },
```

Estou mostrando os dados na view da seguinte maneira:

```
   echo ($transaction['results'][0]['league']['name']);
   echo ($transaction['results'][0]['ss']);
```

Eu preciso pegar esses dados sem indicar qual o Índice, já tentei as seguintes maneiras:

```
     foreach ($transaction as $row){
     echo $row->name;
     }
     //ou
    foreach ($transaction as $row){
    echo $row->results['name'];
    }
    // ou
     foreach ($transaction as $row){
    echo $row->results['league']['name'];
     }
```

Observação: Eu quero sem o índice porque não quero colocar os jogos manualmente que automaticamente seja colocado, exemplo: tenho 10 jogos a tarde da maneira que estou fazendo tenho que colocar 10 índices mas a noite pode ser que tenha só 2 por exemplo.

Comment: Você já tentou fazer: `foreach($transaction['results'] as $row)`?

Comment: Já sim! ele dá a seguinte mensagem: trying to get property 'results' of non-object

Comment: Você consegue dar um `var_dump($transaction)` ou `var_dump($transaction->results)`? Se sim edite sua pergunta com a informação

Comment: Ele vem como NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu ta tentando acessar as propriedades, oque não existe em um array, existem duas formas de fazer oque tu precisa.

**Forma 1** - Utilizar o json como array (que é oque tu tento fazer mas não utilizou certo)

```
$transaction = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($transaction['results'] as $element) {
    echo $element['league']['id'].PHP_EOL;
    echo $element['league']['name'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Forma 2** - Utilizar o json como objeto

```
$transaction = json_decode($json);
foreach ($transaction->results as $element) {
    echo $element->league->id.PHP_EOL;
    echo $element->league->name.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Observe que o segundo parâmetro do json_decode foi passa no primeiro exemplo e no segundo não, isso por que ele serve pra dizer que tu quer transformar os objetos do teu json em array. Mais informação [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: +1 Muito Obrigada! Funcionou